# Strange issue in xcode StoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uistoryboard, pushviewcontroller

```
Unknown class MyViewController in Interface Builder file.
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x1108731e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Label
```

I am having this issue after pushing my ViewController from StoryBoard and connecting label in StoryBoard for specific view. But when I disconnect Label from storyBoard my view appears and crash doesn't happened.

Code below for pushing MyViewController from MainController

```
    - (IBAction)MoveToDetailScreen:(id)sender
{
    MyViewController *custDet = (MyViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:custDet animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be caused by your second ViewController.
Check if you've set the correct Class and Storyboard ID that you can find here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5cry.png
[image: storyboardid]

Comment: Yes everything is specified properly but still crashes :(

Comment: these exceptions are often a result of an unclean storyboard. Open the storyboard in xcode, select File's Owner and click on the "Connection Inspector" (upper right arrow), to see all outlets at once. Check if you've deleted those you don't need anymore because if you deleted an element on your code but you haven't deleted his IBOutlet or IBAction the app will crash.